# Screen flashing on boot, gui repeatedly failing to load, segfault in libmutter

Tags: boot, 16.04, gdm, segmentation-fault

Last night i updated my ubuntu install, today the GUI won't start up.
When i boot, the gui starts up and the screen flickers between the CLI login and black (i assume trying to load the gui repeatedly).

When booting in upstart mode, i have access to the CLI.
After i have manually executed the startx command, the screen goes black to load the gui, but it fails.
Dmesg shows the following output right after this each time i do it:

```
[68.616504] gnome-shell[2337]: segfault at 14 ip 00007f3ac9c51035 sp 00007ffee2163bb0 error 4 in libmutter.so.0.0.0[7f3ac9c17000+f2000]
[69.596696] gnome-shell[2337]: segfault at 14 ip 00007fd2d494e035 sp 00007fff2fe63ce0 error 4 in libmutter.so.0.0.0[7fd2d4914000+f2000]
```

I haven't had problems like this before so i'm unsure how to fix this other than checking for updates every 5 minutes in the hope the broken software has a fix out.

**Update:**

I have found the log of the update that likely contains the problem, i don't know if it proves useful though.

```
Start-Date: 2017-05-16  21:58:43
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.118'
Install: linux-signed-image-4.4.0-78-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-78.99, automatic), linux-tools-4.4.0-78:amd64 (4.4.0-78.99, automatic), linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-78.99, automatic), linux-headers-4.8.0-52:amd64 (4.8.0-52.55~16.04.1, automatic), linux-image-4.8.0-52-generic:amd64 (4.8.0-52.55~16.04.1, automatic), linux-image-extra-4.8.0-52-generic:amd64 (4.8.0-52.55~16.04.1, automatic), linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-78.99, automatic), linux-headers-4.4.0-78-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-78.99, automatic), linux-headers-4.4.0-78:amd64 (4.4.0-78.99, automatic), linux-headers-4.8.0-52-generic:amd64 (4.8.0-52.55~16.04.1, automatic), linux-tools-4.4.0-78-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-78.99, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic:amd64 (4.4.0.77.83, 4.4.0.78.84), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.4.0-77.98, 4.4.0-78.99), qemu-system-mips:amd64 (1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.11, 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.14), qemu-system-misc:amd64 (1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.11, 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.14), qemu-system-ppc:amd64 (1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.11, 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.14), linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04:amd64 (4.8.0.51.22, 4.8.0.52.23), linux-image-generic:amd64 (4.4.0.77.83, 4.4.0.78.84), libgs9:amd64 (9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2.4, 9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2.6), snapd:amd64 (2.24.1, 2.25), linux-signed-image-generic:amd64 (4.4.0.77.83, 4.4.0.78.84), linux-generic-hwe-16.04:amd64 (4.8.0.51.22, 4.8.0.52.23), qemu-system-x86:amd64 (1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.11, 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.14), qemu-user:amd64 (1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.11, 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.14), gdm3:amd64 (3.18.3-0ubuntu2, 3.18.3-0ubuntu2.1), linux-signed-generic:amd64 (4.4.0.77.83, 4.4.0.78.84), gir1.2-gdm-1.0:amd64 (3.18.3-0ubuntu2, 3.18.3-0ubuntu2.1), libgdm1:amd64 (3.18.3-0ubuntu2, 3.18.3-0ubuntu2.1), qemu:amd64 (1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.11, 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.14), qemu-utils:amd64 (1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.11, 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.14), qemu-system-sparc:amd64 (1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.11, 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.14), ghostscript:amd64 (9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2.4, 9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2.6), ghostscript-x:amd64 (9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2.4, 9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2.6), qemu-user-binfmt:amd64 (1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.11, 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.14), libgs9-common:amd64 (9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2.4, 9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2.6), linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04:amd64 (4.8.0.51.22, 4.8.0.52.23), qemu-system-arm:amd64 (1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.11, 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.14), linux-tools-common:amd64 (4.4.0-77.98, 4.4.0-78.99), linux-tools-virtual:amd64 (4.4.0.77.83, 4.4.0.78.84), qemu-block-extra:amd64 (1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.11, 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.14), linux-generic:amd64 (4.4.0.77.83, 4.4.0.78.84), qemu-system-common:amd64 (1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.11, 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.14), qemu-system:amd64 (1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.11, 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.14)
End-Date: 2017-05-16  22:16:29
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the new version of gdm3 and it's related packages fixed the problem.
First time i've fixed anything by trying the same (checking for updates) again later :)